# How to get data for the past x weeks for each type?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have below query which gives me data with three columns - `type`, `amount` and `total` for previous week using `week_number` column.

```
select type,
case
WHEN (type = 'PROC1' AND contractdomicilecode = 'UIT') THEN 450
WHEN (type = 'PROC1' AND contractdomicilecode = 'KJH') THEN 900
WHEN (type = 'PROC2' AND contractdomicilecode = 'LOP') THEN 8840
WHEN (type = 'PROC2' AND contractdomicilecode = 'AWE') THEN 1490
WHEN (type = 'PROC3' AND contractdomicilecode = 'MNH') THEN 1600
WHEN (type = 'PROC3' AND contractdomicilecode = 'LKP') THEN 1900
END as amount,
total
from xyz.orders pa
join
(select clientid as clientid, max(version) as version
from xyz.orders where consumerid IN (select distinct entity_id from abc.items
where week_number = extract(week from current_date) - 1
and item_type like '%Ionize - Data%' )
and createdfor ='BLOCK'
and holder='RELAY_FUTURES'
group by clientid) pb on
pa.clientid = pb.clientid and pa.version = pb.version;
```

Below is the output I get back as of now with above query:

```
type    amount      total
---------------------------
PROC1    450         1768
PROC1    900         123
PROC1    450         456
PROC2    8840        99897
PROC2    1490        2223
PROC2    8840        9876
PROC3    1900        23456
PROC3    1600        12498
PROC3    1600        28756
```

**Problem Statement**

Now I am trying to figure out a way by which I can get data for past 6 weeks (not including current week). Basically I want to get `amount`, `total` for each type for past 6 weeks as shown below.

```
 week   type    amount      total
----------------------------------
  46    PROC1    450         1768
  46    PROC1    900         123
  46    PROC1    450         456
  46    PROC2    8840        99897
  46    PROC2    1490        2223
  46    PROC2    8840        9876
  46    PROC3    1900        23456
  46    PROC3    1600        12498
  46    PROC3    1600        28756
  45    PROC1    450         1768
  45    PROC1    900         123
  45    PROC1    450         456
  45    PROC2    8840        99897
  45    PROC2    1490        2223
  45    PROC2    8840        9876
  45    PROC3    1900        23456
  45    PROC3    1600        12498
  45    PROC3    1600        28756
  44    PROC1    450         1768
  44    PROC1    900         123
  44    PROC1    450         456
  44    PROC2    8840        99897
  44    PROC2    1490        2223
  44    PROC2    8840        9876
  44    PROC3    1900        23456
  44    PROC3    1600        12498
  44    PROC3    1600        28756
  43    PROC1    450         1768
  43    PROC1    900         123
  43    PROC1    450         456
  43    PROC2    8840        99897
  43    PROC2    1490        2223
  43    PROC2    8840        9876
  43    PROC3    1900        23456
  43    PROC3    1600        12498
  43    PROC3    1600        28756
  42    PROC1    450         1768
  42    PROC1    900         123
  42    PROC1    450         456
  42    PROC2    8840        99897
  42    PROC2    1490        2223
  42    PROC2    8840        9876
  42    PROC3    1900        23456
  42    PROC3    1600        12498
  42    PROC3    1600        28756
  41    PROC1    450         1768
  41    PROC1    900         123
  41    PROC1    450         456
  41    PROC2    8840        99897
  41    PROC2    1490        2223
  41    PROC2    8840        9876
  41    PROC3    1900        23456
  41    PROC3    1600        12498
  41    PROC3    1600        28756
```

Is this possible to do by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try adding the following code to your query, right after the first `select` in line 1, if the column `current_date` is present in the `xyz.orders` table:

```
extract(week from current_date) as week,
```

To obtain the past number of weeks (6 in your case), a filter will be used after the line of `from xyz.orders pa`:

```
where datediff(week, extract(week, current_date)-6, extract(week, current_date)+1) = 6
```

The filter might need to be slightly adjusted, but when you see the output you should be able to find what needs to be adjusted.

Some more info in the `DATEDIFF` function used in the filter above from the MS docs might be a helpful reference.

[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

With the above changes, here is the updated query and comments as to the specifics added from your original code.

```
select
    extract(week from current_date) as week, -- added code
    type,
    case
        WHEN (type = 'PROC1' AND contractdomicilecode = 'UIT') THEN 450
        WHEN (type = 'PROC1' AND contractdomicilecode = 'KJH') THEN 900
        WHEN (type = 'PROC2' AND contractdomicilecode = 'LOP') THEN 8840
        WHEN (type = 'PROC2' AND contractdomicilecode = 'AWE') THEN 1490
        WHEN (type = 'PROC3' AND contractdomicilecode = 'MNH') THEN 1600
        WHEN (type = 'PROC3' AND contractdomicilecode = 'LKP') THEN 1900
    END as amount,
    total
    from xyz.orders pa
    where datediff(week, extract(week, current_date)-6, extract(week, current_date)+1) = 6 -- added code
    join
    (select clientid as clientid, max(version) as version
        from xyz.orders where consumerid IN (select distinct entity_id from abc.items
        where week_number = extract(week from current_date) - 1
        and item_type like '%Ionize - Data%' )
        and createdfor ='BLOCK'
        and holder='RELAY_FUTURES'
        group by clientid) pb on
        pa.clientid = pb.clientid and pa.version = pb.version;
```

Comment: yeah but how can I get all those data for past 6 weeks then?

Comment: Try out the filter above in the updated answer. Also, provided a link to the official docs on the function used, might be of some help.

Comment: So what happens to this condition inside my inner query - `where week_number = extract(week from current_date) - 1`? I am kinda confuse. Can you provide an updated query example with your suggestion?

Comment: The answer is updated. I believe in that inner query, for the line you specified, it is filtering the records 1 week back from the `current_date`.

Comment: yeah so this 6 weeks thing doesn't need to be modified there? I just wanted to make sure

Comment: Well, since in it's current state the code you have is 1 week back, yes. If you would like for it to match the same time period as the outer period then you may apply the same filter on the inner `where' and verify the results.

Comment: I tried your suggestion in the chat and it runs fine but I only get one week of data. Not sure why?
Do you think it needs to be added somewhere else?

Comment: @AndyP - I responded in the chat. Other than 1) simplifying the query to debug (i.e. remove the join and try the filter first there) and 2) seeing sample data to re-create it, that is as much as I can help at the moment.