# Subquery has too many columns error while getting data for past X weeks?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have below query which gives me data for previous week as shown below. It returns data with these columns: `type`, `amount` and `total` for previous week using `week_number` column which is used in inner subquery.

```
select type,
case
WHEN (type = 'PROC1' AND code = 'UIT') THEN 450
WHEN (type = 'PROC1' AND code = 'KJH') THEN 900
WHEN (type = 'PROC2' AND code = 'LOP') THEN 8840
WHEN (type = 'PROC2' AND code = 'AWE') THEN 1490
WHEN (type = 'PROC3' AND code = 'MNH') THEN 1600
WHEN (type = 'PROC3' AND code = 'LKP') THEN 1900
END as amount,
total
from xyz.orders pa
join
(select clientid as clientid, max(version) as version
from xyz.orders where consumerid IN (select distinct entity_id from abc.items
where week_number = extract(week from current_date) - 1
and item_type like '%Ionize - Data%' )
and createdfor ='BLOCK'
and holder='RELAY_FUTURES'
group by clientid) pb on
pa.clientid = pb.clientid and pa.version = pb.version;
```

Below is the output I get back as of now with my above query which is for previous week:

```
type    amount      total
---------------------------
PROC1    450         1768
PROC1    900         123
PROC1    450         456
PROC2    8840        99897
PROC2    1490        2223
PROC2    8840        9876
PROC3    1900        23456
PROC3    1600        12498
PROC3    1600        28756
```

In my above query I have inner subquery as shown below which returns data for previous week and then output of this is used in the outer query.

```
select distinct entity_id from abc.items
where week_number = extract(week from current_date) - 1
and item_type like '%Ionize - Data%'
```

Now I am trying to figure out a way by which I can get data for past 6 weeks (not including current week) and also grouped by each week so I think we need to modify above inner query so that it can give me data for past 6 weeks and then group by each week somehow at the outer query. Basically I want to get `amount`, `total` for each `type` for past 6 weeks as shown below. Somehow I need to add `week_number` column as well in my final output.

**Expected Output**

```
week_number     type    amount      total
--------------------------------------------
  46            PROC1    450         1768
  46            PROC1    900         123
  46            PROC1    450         456
  46            PROC2    8840        99897
  46            PROC2    1490        2223
  46            PROC2    8840        9876
  46            PROC3    1900        23456
  46            PROC3    1600        12498
  46            PROC3    1600        28756
  45            PROC1    450         1768
  45            PROC1    900         123
  45            PROC1    450         456
  45            PROC2    8840        99897
  45            PROC2    1490        2223
  45            PROC2    8840        9876
  45            PROC3    1900        23456
  45            PROC3    1600        12498
  45            PROC3    1600        28756
  44            PROC1    450         1768
  44            PROC1    900         123
  44            PROC1    450         456
  44            PROC2    8840        99897
  44            PROC2    1490        2223
  44            PROC2    8840        9876
  44            PROC3    1900        23456
  44            PROC3    1600        12498
  44            PROC3    1600        28756
  43            PROC1    450         1768
  43            PROC1    900         123
  43            PROC1    450         456
  43            PROC2    8840        99897
  43            PROC2    1490        2223
  43            PROC2    8840        9876
  43            PROC3    1900        23456
  43            PROC3    1600        12498
  43            PROC3    1600        28756
  42            PROC1    450         1768
  42            PROC1    900         123
  42            PROC1    450         456
  42            PROC2    8840        99897
  42            PROC2    1490        2223
  42            PROC2    8840        9876
  42            PROC3    1900        23456
  42            PROC3    1600        12498
  42            PROC3    1600        28756
  41            PROC1    450         1768
  41            PROC1    900         123
  41            PROC1    450         456
  41            PROC2    8840        99897
  41            PROC2    1490        2223
  41            PROC2    8840        9876
  41            PROC3    1900        23456
  41            PROC3    1600        12498
  41            PROC3    1600        28756
```

So I tried with below query by modifying inner subquery but it gives me error as `invalid operation:subquery has too many columns`. Any idea what is wrong I am doing here?

```
select type,
case
WHEN (type = 'PROC1' AND code = 'UIT') THEN 450
WHEN (type = 'PROC1' AND code = 'KJH') THEN 900
WHEN (type = 'PROC2' AND code = 'LOP') THEN 8840
WHEN (type = 'PROC2' AND code = 'AWE') THEN 1490
WHEN (type = 'PROC3' AND code = 'MNH') THEN 1600
WHEN (type = 'PROC3' AND code = 'LKP') THEN 1900
END as amount,
total
from xyz.orders pa
join
(select clientid as clientid, max(version) as version
from xyz.orders where consumerid IN (select week_number, entity_id from abc.items
where week_number >= extract(week from current_date) - 6 
  and week_number <= extract(week from current_date) - 1
  and item_type like '%Ionize - Data%'
order by week_number desc )
and createdfor ='BLOCK'
and holder='RELAY_FUTURES'
group by clientid) pb on
pa.clientid = pb.clientid and pa.version = pb.version;
```

I modified my inner query to be like this:

```
select week_number, entity_id from abc.items
where week_number >= extract(week from current_date) - 6 
  and week_number <= extract(week from current_date) - 1
  and item_type like '%Ionize - Data%'
order by week_number desc
```

It could be possible that I am doing it completely wrong to achieve the desired output so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get data for the past x weeks for each type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64897019/how-to-get-data-for-the-past-x-weeks-for-each-type)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not so I went different route by changing inner sub query but I get an error here.

Comment: Remove order by in the sub query. You can't do a Order By in Sub Queries.

Comment: I tried by removing `order by` but still same error - `invalid operation:subquery has too many columns` @SaiAbhiramInapala

Comment: In your original query what happens when you use week_number >= extract(week from current_date) - 6. Does it work?

Comment: But I need data in the format of `Expected Output` as shown in my question where it can show `type` `amount` and `total` for each week.

Comment: @AndyP this is problematic ```where consumerid IN (select week_number, entity_id ``` your subquery is returning 2 columns but part to the left of IN has only 1 column (consumerid). I didnt check the logic of your query but it seems you need this: ```where (week_number, consumerid) in (select week_number, entity_id ...```

Answer (score 4):

Andy the issue is with the WHERE clause

```
where consumerid IN (select week_number, entity_id from abc.items
where week_number >= extract(week from current_date) - 6 
  and week_number <= extract(week from current_date) - 1
  and item_type like '%Ionize - Data%'
order by week_number desc )
```

As the clause is looking to see if "consumerid" is a member of the list resulting from the subquery.  However this subquery is returning 2 columns and Redshift cannot compare 1 column to 2 columns.  Just remove "week_number," from the select and this error will be resolved.

```
where consumerid IN (select entity_id from abc.items
where week_number >= extract(week from current_date) - 6 
  and week_number <= extract(week from current_date) - 1
  and item_type like '%Ionize - Data%'
order by week_number desc )
```

Comment: Thanks Bill but will this help me with the output I need for my query? As you can see above I have `Expected Output` what else I need to do to get in that format? I need data group by weeks. After that change I can run my query fine but I am confuse on how to get final output group by week.

Comment: Also this where condition for multiple week will fail because currently it's January and current week is 2 so it will be in negative right? Is there any way we can use week_number column to get correct past 6 weeks?

Comment: Andy, It will be hard to understand how this query is suppose to work without some source data (sample input data and expected output from this data).  One issue I see is that "extract(week from current_date) - 6" is not going to work as you expect when the week number rolls over at the new year.  As I mentioned I do consult on making Redshift work for people.  The answer posted addresses the issue of this topic - If there is a need for general query work I recommend bringing in the talent needed.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Let me dig into this issue more and see if I can figure it out. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

The code below should suffice - not tested using Redshift interpreter however.

**week_number**: Replace the IN with join and select your week_number as below.
It's not entirely clear which week_number you are looking for here. To the outsider, the max version is retrieved for a
5-week time boxed period, so if a record on xyz.orders has week 45 then the max version retrieved in the query below will be for
Week 39 - Week 44.
So the query below should present the following:

```
Week 45, 
Type, 
Amount for latest in Week 39 - Week 44, 
Total.
```

Negative week number - see commented code below.

```
With Maxfor5WeekPeriod as 
(
    select 
        MaxVersions.week_number,
        O.clientid as clientid, 
        max(O.version) as version
    from xyz.orders O
    join
    (
        select 
            entity_id,
            week_number
        from abc.items
        where 
        --Something like this should resolve your start of year issue. 
        date_part(w,dateadd(week,-6,current_date)) >= week_number 
        and date_part(w,dateadd(week,-1,current_date)) <= week_number
        and item_type like '%Ionize - Data%'
    ) MaxVersions on 
    entity_id = Consumerid 
    and O.createdfor ='BLOCK'
    and O.holder='RELAY_FUTURES'
    group by O.clientid,MaxVersions.week_number
)
select 
    M.week_number, 
    pa.type,
    case
    WHEN (pa.type = 'PROC1' AND contractdomicilecode = 'UIT') THEN 450
    WHEN (pa.type = 'PROC1' AND contractdomicilecode = 'KJH') THEN 900
    WHEN (pa.type = 'PROC2' AND contractdomicilecode = 'LOP') THEN 8840
    WHEN (pa.type = 'PROC2' AND contractdomicilecode = 'AWE') THEN 1490
    WHEN (pa.type = 'PROC3' AND contractdomicilecode = 'MNH') THEN 1600
    WHEN (pa.type = 'PROC3' AND contractdomicilecode = 'LKP') THEN 1900
    END as amount,
    pa.total
from 
xyz.orders pa
join Maxfor5WeekPeriod M 
on pa.clientid = M.clientid and 
pa.version = M.version
```

General point: Redshift docs include a reference to Common Table Expressions - they would make this code somewhat tidier. Answer does benefit significantly from earlier clarifications from the other contributors. However, please note I am not familiar with Redshift.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it gives me syntax error because `week_number` column is only available in `abc.items` but it's not available in `xyz.orders` so it complains as `Invalid operation: column o.week_number does not exist;`.

Comment: Also if you look at my first query in the question at the top - it only works on one week which is previous week so the output it generates is for the last week only. Now I just need to modify that inner query in such a way so that I can get data for past 6 week but group by each week. Meaning I want to see a view where I have `week_number` column coming out from the inner most query to the top and all the data for that week just like it shows from my first query in the question.

Comment: Replaced O.week_number with MaxVersions.week_number, removed "and MaxVersions.WeekNumber = O.week_number"

Comment: Got it also we need to change this `O.week_number` too right in the group by clause?

Comment: For some reason data is not matching when I run my original query just on one week manually and then if I run your suggestion and try to compare it, it doesn't matches. Any thoughts why it could be? Do you think this has anything to do with using join instead of original IN clause query?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't as I'm sure you understand, since I don't have the data and I don't really understand what "not matching" refers to in the context of the data. I would suggest taking each of the three select statement in my query and running each separately and filter on one customer or entity. Start with the MaxVersions query, pick a a single customer then run the next query to find the latest version, then the outermost query using the version and client id. This will allow you to reduce the problem to a smaller set of data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227615/discussion-between-johnny-fitz-and-andyp).

Comment: @JohnnyFitz I have a redshift sql question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66038453/how-to-use-value-from-the-outer-table-in-my-subqueries-in-redshift). I wanted to see if you can help me out there. I am kinda stuck on this for a while so needed some help. Sorry for pinging like this.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the distinct entity_id, week_number combination for the past 6 weeks.(Table 1)

```
SELECT DISTINCT entity_id, week_number
       FROM abc.items
       WHERE week_number >= Extract(week FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 6
         AND week_number <= Extract(week FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1
         AND item_type LIKE '%Ionize - Data%'
```

To get the max version of orders corresponding to a unique combination of clientId and Consumer ID

```
SELECT clientid AS clientid, Max(version) AS version, consumerid
          FROM xyz.orders
          WHERE createdfor = 'BLOCK'
            AND holder = 'RELAY_FUTURES'
          GROUP BY consumerid, clientid
```

Join the above two tables to get clientId, version, and Week Number.

```
select xo.clientid    AS clientid,
             xo.version     AS version,
             ai.week_number as week_number from (SELECT DISTINCT entity_id, week_number
       FROM abc.items
       WHERE week_number >= Extract(week FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 6
         AND week_number <= Extract(week FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1
         AND item_type LIKE '%Ionize - Data%')
         ai LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT clientid     AS clientid,
                 Max(version) AS version,
                 consumerid
          FROM xyz.orders
          WHERE createdfor = 'BLOCK'
            AND holder = 'RELAY_FUTURES'
          GROUP BY consumerid, clientid) xo
      ON ai.entity_id = xo.consumerid
```

Left join is used to discard all the consumer id not present in Table 1.

Use the above query as inner query.

```
SELECT pb.week_number,
       pa.type,
       CASE
           WHEN (type = 'PROC1'
               AND contractdomicilecode = 'UIT') THEN 450
           WHEN (type = 'PROC1'
               AND contractdomicilecode = 'KJH') THEN 900
           WHEN (type = 'PROC2'
               AND contractdomicilecode = 'LOP') THEN 8840
           WHEN (type = 'PROC2'
               AND contractdomicilecode = 'AWE') THEN 1490
           WHEN (type = 'PROC3'
               AND contractdomicilecode = 'MNH') THEN 1600
           WHEN (type = 'PROC3'
               AND contractdomicilecode = 'LKP') THEN 1900
           END AS amount,
       pa.total
FROM xyz.orders pa
         JOIN
     (select xo.clientid    AS clientid,
             xo.version     AS version,
             ai.week_number as week_number from (SELECT DISTINCT entity_id, week_number
       FROM abc.items
       WHERE week_number >= Extract(week FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 6
         AND week_number <= Extract(week FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1
         AND item_type LIKE '%Ionize - Data%')
         ai LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT clientid     AS clientid,
                 Max(version) AS version,
                 consumerid
          FROM xyz.orders
          WHERE createdfor = 'BLOCK'
            AND holder = 'RELAY_FUTURES'
          GROUP BY consumerid, clientid) xo
      ON ai.entity_id = xo.consumerid) pb
     ON pa.clientid = pb.clientid
         AND pa.version = pb.version;
```