# Window function is not allowed in where clause redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a `dates` CTE in my below query where I am using `limit` clause which I don't want to use it. I am trying to understand on how to rewrite my `dates` CTE so that I can avoid using `limit 8` query.

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT (date_trunc('week', getdate() + INTERVAL '1 day')::date - 7 * (row_number() over (order by true) - 1) - INTERVAL '1 day')::date AS week_column
    FROM dimensions.customer LIMIT 8
)
SELECT
dates.week_column, 
'W' || ceiling(date_part('week', dates.week_column + INTERVAL '1 day')) AS week_number,
COUNT(DISTINCT features.client_id) AS total
FROM dimensions.program features 
JOIN dates ON features.last_update <= dates.week_column
WHERE features.type = 'capacity'
AND features.status = 'CURRENT'
GROUP BY dates.week_column
ORDER by dates.week_column DESC
```

Below is the output I get from my inner `dates` CTE query:

```
SELECT (date_trunc('week', getdate() + INTERVAL '1 day')::date - 7 * (row_number() over (order by true) - 1) - INTERVAL '1 day')::date AS week_column
FROM dimensions.customer LIMIT 8
```

Output from `dates` CTE :

```
2021-01-10
2021-01-03
2020-12-27
2020-12-20
2020-12-13
2020-12-06
2020-11-29
2020-11-22
```

Is there any way to avoid using `limit 8` in my CTE query and still get same output? Our platform doesn't allow us to run queries if it has `limit` clause in it so trying to see if I can rewrite it differently in sql redshift?

If I modify my `dates` CTE query like this, then it gives me error as `window function is not allowed in where clause`.

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT (date_trunc('week', getdate() + INTERVAL '1 day')::date - 7 * (row_number() over (order by true) - 1) - INTERVAL '1 day')::date AS week_column,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as seqnum
    FROM dimensions.customer
    WHERE seqnum <= 8;
)
....
```

**Update**

Something like this you mean?

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT (date_trunc('week', getdate() + INTERVAL '1 day')::date - 7 * (row_number() over (order by true) - 1) - INTERVAL '1 day')::date AS week_column,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as seqnum
    FROM dimensions.customer
)
SELECT
dates.week_column, 
'W' || ceiling(date_part('week', dates.week_column + INTERVAL '1 day')) AS week_number,
COUNT(DISTINCT features.client_id) AS total
FROM dimensions.program features 
JOIN dates ON features.last_update <= dates.week_column
WHERE dates.seqnum <= 8 
AND features.type = 'capacity'
AND features.status = 'CURRENT'
GROUP BY dates.week_column
ORDER by dates.week_column DESC
```

Comment: I think in the last query you can use a subquery and put where clause outside the subquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move your WHERE clause to the outer SELECT.  Seqnum doesn't exists until the CTE runs but does exist when the result of the CTE is consumed.

UPDATE ...

After moving the where clause AndyP got a correlated subquery error coming from a WHERE clause not included in the posted query.  As shown in this somewhat modified query:

```
WITH dates AS
(
  SELECT (DATE_TRUNC('week',getdate () +INTERVAL '1 day')::DATE- 7*(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TRUE) - 1) -INTERVAL '1 day')::DATE AS week_of
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS X UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS X UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS X UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS X UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS X UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS X UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS X UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS X)
)
SELECT dates.week_of,
       'W' || CEILING(DATE_PART('week',dates.week_of +INTERVAL '1 day')) AS week_number,
       COUNT(DISTINCT features.id) AS total
FROM dimensions.program features
  JOIN dates ON features.last_update <= dates.week_of
WHERE features.version = (SELECT MAX(version)
                                  FROM headers f2
                                  WHERE features.id = f2.id
                                  AND   features.type = f2.type
                                  AND   f2.last_update <= dates.week_of)
AND   features.type = 'type'
AND   features.status = 'live'
GROUP BY dates.week_of
ORDER BY dates.week_of DESC;
```

This was an interesting replacement of a correlated query with a join due to the inequality in the correlated sub query.  We thought others might be helped by posting the final solution.  This works:

```
WITH dates AS
(
  SELECT (DATE_TRUNC('week',getdate () +INTERVAL '1 day')::DATE- 7*(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TRUE) - 1) -INTERVAL '1 day')::DATE AS week_of
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS X UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS X UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS X UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS X UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS X UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS X UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS X UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS X)
)
SELECT dates.week_of,
       'W' || CEILING(DATE_PART('week',dates.week_of +INTERVAL '1 day')) AS week_number,
       COUNT(DISTINCT features.carrier_id) AS total
FROM dimensions.program features
  JOIN dates ON features.last_update <= dates.week_of
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(MAX(version)) OVER(Partition by id, type Order by dates.weeks_of rows unbounded preceding) AS feature_version,
               f2.id,
               f2.type,
               dates.week_of
        FROM dimensions.headers f2
        JOIN dates ON f2.last_update <= dates.week_of
        GROUP BY f2.id,
                 f2.type,
                 dates.week_of) f2
    ON features.id = f2.id
   AND features.type = f2.type
   AND f2.week_of = dates.week_of
   AND features.version = f2.version
WHERE features.type = 'type'
AND   features.status = 'live'
GROUP BY dates.week_of
ORDER BY dates.week_of DESC;
```

Needing to make a data segment that had all the possible Max(version) for all possible week_of values was the key.  Hopefully having both of these queries posted will help other fix correlated subquery errors.

Comment: I updated my question with the query. Is that what you mean? Just trying to make sure.

Comment: I am getting an error if I use my updated query in the question. Error is - `Invalid operation: Output timestamp out of range after subtracting constant. Details: ----------------------------------------------- error: Output timestamp out of range after subtracting constant.`

Comment: How many rows are in dimensions.customer?  You are trying to make 8 manufactured rows, are you staring with millions?  This error looks like you are calculating a date that is not valid - before 4713 BC.

Comment: I tried this `select count(*) from dimensions.customer` and count I got is `452430`. Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: So do you only ever need 8 rows from the CTE or are there cases when you need many, many more?

Comment: I just need 8 rows only from that `dates` CTE. That's the only case but its output should match exactly what I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Change your FROM clause in the CTE to: 
FROM ( SELECT 1 as X UNION ALL SELECT 1 as X UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 as X UNION ALL SELECT 1 as X UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 as X UNION ALL SELECT 1 as X UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 as X UNION ALL SELECT 1 as X)

Comment: There are other ways to make an 8 row input set but this is easy to understand

Comment: you mean like this - `WITH dates AS (
    SELECT (date_trunc('week', getdate() + INTERVAL '1 day')::date - 7 * (row_number() over (order by true) - 1) - INTERVAL '1 day')::date AS week_column,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as seqnum
    FROM ( SELECT 1 as X UNION ALL SELECT 1 as X UNION ALL SELECT 1 as X UNION ALL SELECT 1 as X UNION ALL SELECT 1 as X UNION ALL SELECT 1 as X UNION ALL SELECT 1 as X UNION ALL SELECT 1 as X) 
)`

Comment: You can use a system table as the input of the CTE as many of these are only a few hundred rows long

Comment: Hi Bill, I have another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64994981/subquery-has-too-many-columns-error-while-getting-data-for-past-x-weeks) which was opened from quite sometime but didn't get any answer. If you have time can you help me with that as well.