# How to use value from the outer table in my subqueries in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, subquery, amazon-redshift

I have a query as shown below in which I have three different CTE's `dates`, `active` and `featuretype` which I am using in my main select outer query.

```
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT 
    (
      DATE_TRUNC(
        'week', 
        getdate () + INTERVAL '1 day'
      ):: DATE - 7 *(
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          ORDER BY 
            TRUE
        ) -1
      ) - INTERVAL '1 day'
    ):: DATE AS week_of 
  FROM 
    (
      SELECT 
        1 AS X 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 
        1 AS X 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 
        1 AS X 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 
        1 AS X 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 
        1 AS X 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 
        1 AS X 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 
        1 AS X 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 
        1 AS X
    )
), 
active as (
  select 
    client_id, 
    update_timestamp, 
    version, 
    status 
  from 
    kites.customer c1 
  where 
    (
      c1.is_customer = false 
      or c1.is_customer is NULL
    ) 
    AND c1.status IN ('TEST1', 'TEST2', 'TEST3') 
    and c1.mgt_name = 'ABC'
), 
featuretype AS (
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM 
    kites.program 
  WHERE 
    client_type = 'compliance-data' 
    AND client_status = 'TEST1'
) 
SELECT 
  dates.week_of, 
  DATE_PART(d, dates.week_of) AS day, 
  count(DISTINCT active.client_id) as total_count, 
  COUNT(
    CASE WHEN active.status = 'TEST1' THEN active.client_id END
  ) AS count1, 
FROM 
  active 
  join dates on active.update_timestamp <= dates.week_of 
  LEFT JOIN featuretype p1 ON active.client_id = p1.client_id
-- how can I rewrite this where subquery by avoiding correlated subquery error?
WHERE 
  active.version = (
    Select 
      MAX(version) 
    from 
      kites.customer c2 
    where 
      active.client_id = c2.client_id 
      and c2.update_timestamp <= dates.week_of
  ) 
  AND p1.client_version = (
    Select 
      MAX(client_version) 
    from 
      kites.program p2 
    where 
      p1.client_id = p2.client_id 
      AND p1.client_type = p2.client_type 
      AND p2.update_timestamp <= dates.week_of
  ) 
GROUP BY 
  week_of 
ORDER by 
  week_of DESC 
limit 
  7;
```

I am trying to figure out on how to write my two subqueries in my where clause at the end using join or any other way. As of now when I run this query as it is, it gives me below error. I tried converting those where clause subquery using JOIN but I still get same error.

```
Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error
```

Is there any way I can use `lateral join` in redshift since I need to use value from the outer table (CTE's) column in my subqueries? Reading more about looks like I can't use it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A correlated sub-query is when you need to reevaluate a select clause for every row of a table.  When dealing with the very large databases that are on Redshift this creates massive amounts of reevaluation and runtime.  Combined with the network clustered nature of Redshift that drives a lot of this reevaluation across the networks and you can see how these types of query structures create problems.

You query has 2 such correlated sub-queries and is a bit large to gain understanding of how to address so let me cut it down so show how you can attack it.  Using this reduced version I'll try to show how it can be done.

```
WITH active AS
(
       SELECT client_id,
              update_timestamp,
              version,
              status
       FROM   kites.customer c1
       WHERE  (
                     c1.is_customer = FALSE
              OR     c1.is_customer IS NULL )
       AND    c1.status IN ('TEST1',
                            'TEST2',
                            'TEST3')
       AND    c1.mgt_name = 'ABC' )
SELECT   dates.week_of,
         Date_part(d, dates.week_of)      AS day,
         Count(DISTINCT active.client_id) AS total_count
from     active
join     dates
ON       active.update_timestamp <= dates.week_of
WHERE    active.version =
         (
                SELECT max(version)
                FROM   kites.customer c2
                WHERE  active.client_id = c2.client_id
                AND    c2.update_timestamp <= dates.week_of )
GROUP BY week_of
ORDER BY week_of DESC limit 7;
```

Now we have just the 1 correlated sub-query - "active" is based on the table customer and so is the select in the WHERE clause.  This isn't a problem in itself but since the WHERE clause wants the MAX(version) for the current rows client_id and for a range of dates you can see that this WHERE clause cannot resolve to one set of data and keeps needing to change for every row in active.

The fix is to create a set of data that has all the possible MAX(version)'s and join this set in ON active.version = the_computed_max_version_for_this_client_id_and_date_range.  We just need to compute this set.  Since this is a MAX() over a range of dates for each client_id it calls for a MAX() window function.

```
MAX(version) OVER (PARTITION by client_id ORDER BY dates.week_of ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as max_version
```

Putting these together we get a first attempt of

```
WITH active AS
(
       SELECT client_id,
              update_timestamp,
              version,
              status
       FROM   kites.customer c1
       WHERE  (
                     c1.is_customer = FALSE
              OR     c1.is_customer IS NULL )
       AND    c1.status IN ('TEST1',
                            'TEST2',
                            'TEST3')
       AND    c1.mgt_name = 'ABC' )
SELECT   dates.week_of,
         Date_part(d, dates.week_of)      AS day,
         Count(DISTINCT active.client_id) AS total_count
FROM     active
join     dates
ON       active.update_timestamp <= dates.week_of
join
         (
                  SELECT   Max(version) over (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY dates.week_of ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS max_version
                  FROM     kites.customer c2
                  join     dates
                  ON       c2.update_timestamp <= dates.week_of
                  WHERE    c2.update_timestamp <= dates.week_of ) maxv
ON       active.version = maxv.max_version
GROUP BY week_of
ORDER BY week_of DESC limit 7;
```

I cannot promise this is fully correct as I don't have data to test with but hopefully this gives you a start.  If you need more specific help you will likely need to provide data setup and expected results and I'm sure the community can get it working.

Adding a 2nd version that may be what is needed (depends on the the data you have):

```
WITH active AS
(
       SELECT client_id,
              update_timestamp,
              version,
              status
       FROM   kites.customer c1
       WHERE  (
                     c1.is_customer = FALSE
              OR     c1.is_customer IS NULL )
       AND    c1.status IN ('TEST1',
                            'TEST2',
                            'TEST3')
       AND    c1.mgt_name = 'ABC' )
SELECT   dates.week_of,
         Date_part(d, dates.week_of)      AS day,
         Count(DISTINCT active.client_id) AS total_count
FROM     active
join     dates
ON       active.update_timestamp <= dates.week_of
join
         (
                  SELECT   Max(version) over (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY dates.week_of ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS max_version,
                      client_id, week_of         
                  FROM     kites.customer c2
                  join     dates
                  ON       c2.update_timestamp <= dates.week_of
                  WHERE    c2.update_timestamp <= dates.week_of ) maxv
ON       active.version = maxv.max_version 
   and active.client_id = maxv.client_id
   and date.week_of = maxv.week_of
GROUP BY week_of
ORDER BY week_of DESC limit 7;
```

Comment: Thanks Bill for your detailed explanation. Reading it out and trying to understand everything but just quick question for now. This line `ON active.client_id = maxv.max_version` should be `ON active. version = maxv.max_version` correct?

Comment: When I try running I get this error now - `Invalid operation: column "date" does not exist in c2, dates, unnamed_join;`. Any thoughts why is that?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it should be dates.week_of as this is the <= in your sub-query.  Not knowing your data I'm a bit out on a limb.  Answer edited to reflect this.

Comment: That fixed the syntax error but now when I run this [query](https://pastebin.com/hU6um0ZX), it just keeps running forever. I am not able to figure it out what's wrong. Any help will be appreciated if possible. I am kinda stuck on this from quite sometime. I know I don't have data setup and expected results since the data and results are pretty huge for me to share it here.

Comment: Is there any usual suspects you can spot which I can check it out?

Comment: There could be another issue in the query I scratched out - if you could post the explain plan it should show what is going on.  I can also see that the new data set is too large or under qualified in the ON clause - I just have no insight into the data to know.  One change to try is to add week_of to the ON clause.  I'll drop a revised version for this in the answer.

Comment: Also could be that client_id needs to be in the join on clause.  I just don't know what the data looks like.  I added that too in the 2nd version.  You will need to weigh in on which are needed.